# Live Preview doesn't match Elementor Preview

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to this elementor, I'm building a wedding website for my relative for his wedding to come.
I have some problems with the Elementor. When I choose an image and make the position 'Absolute', the preview is good enough. But when I published it, the live website doesn't look like what it's supposed to look like on Elementor.
The Preview on Elementor looks like this:
[The Preview on Elementor looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFl9z.png)
But The Live Website looks like this:
[But The Live Website looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQiRV.png)

So far I've tried some fix from Youtube like changing the Elementor CSS Print Method to Internal Embedding.

Does Anyone have any idea how to fix this?
It'll be great if anyone can help.

Thank You.
Ps: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

When things don't match up perfectly between previews and the live site, it could sometimes be related to caching issues or conflicting plugins. Make sure to clear your website cache and browser cache to ensure you're viewing the most recent version.

Additionally, double-check for any conflicting plugins that might be affecting your design. Remember, you're learning and growing through this process, and each hurdle you overcome brings you closer to achieving the vision you have for the website.